Userscript to add characters before and after selection with a shortcut
I tend to use Chrome and MediaWiki's WikiEditor to add internal links, but it requires clicking on the respective button. Is there a way to either insert the characters with a shortcut or activate that button with a shortcut? For example the outcome should look like these examples when the shortcut is pressed on selected text:
[[selectedtext]]
[[selected text]]

Alternatively, the span element of the insert link is
<span class="oo-ui-iconElement-icon oo-ui-icon-wikiText"></span>


This will toggle between selected-text and [[selected-text]] with Ctrl + ] :
const bounds = ',.;:?!(){}';

const escape = string => string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
const wordStartRegex = new RegExp(`[^\\s${escape(bounds)}]+$`);
const wordEndRegex = new RegExp(`^[^\\s${escape(bounds)}]+`)

function toggleSelectionToLink(textarea) {
    let start = textarea.selectionStart;
    let end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    let text = textarea.value;

    if (start === end) {
        let match = text.slice(0, start).match(wordStartRegex);
        if (!match) return;

        textarea.selectionStart = start = match.index;
        textarea.selectionEnd = end = text.slice(start).match(wordEndRegex)[0].length + start;
    }

    let selectedText = text.slice(start, end);
    let newText = selectedText.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/gs, '$1');
    newText = selectedText !== newText ? newText : selectedText.replace(selectedText.trim(), `[[${selectedText.trim()}]]`);

    document.execCommand('insertText', false, newText);

    // preserve selection (range):
    textarea.selectionStart = start;
    textarea.selectionEnd = start + newText.length;
}

window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
     if (e.ctrlKey && e.code === 'BracketRight' && e.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') {
         toggleSelectionToLink(e.target);
     }
})


Brilliant! Is it possible to make it also select a single word if there is no selection and cursor is within the word (i.e. any word containing any letter characters, including Greek extended/Cyrillic)?

Also, if an extra space is selected at the end of the selection, then do not include that space in the link, so instead of [[selectedtext ]], create a link with [[selectedtext]] (and of course leave the extra space at the end).

@greektranslator I edited the answer with the changes, it should now handle extra spaces and select the word at the cursor.

Thank you! This is almost perfect, only problem if there is punctuation after the word when cursor is inside it, it includes the punctuation, like so this, becomes [[this,]] and this. becomes [[this.]] and so on.

Same applies with parentheses, ie [[(word)]] instead of ([[word]])

@greektranslator see the edit, you can  add more characters that you want to exclude to bounds.

@greektranslator no problem!
